# Reinforcement Learning coach : Saver fails to restore agent's checkpoint

Tags: python, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm using [rl coach](https://nervanasystems.github.io/coach/index.html) through AWS Sagemaker, and I'm running in an issue that I struggle to understand.

I'm performing RL using AWS Sagemaker for the learning, and AWS Robomaker for the environment, like in [DeepRacer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deepracer/latest/developerguide/deepracer-how-it-works-service-architecture.html) which uses rl coach as well. In fact, the code only little differs with the [DeepRacer code](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/d6a25381975332aa79df61144fc0c2421bd5168c/reinforcement_learning/rl_deepracer_robomaker_coach_gazebo) on the learning side. But the environment is completely different though.

What happens:

- The graph manager initialization succeeds
- A first checkpoint is generated (and uploaded to S3)
- The agent loads the first checkpoint
- The agent performs N episodes with the first policy
- The graph manager fetches the N episodes
- The graph manager performs 1 training step and create a second checkpoint (uploaded to S3)
- **The agent fails to restore the model with the second checkpoint.**

The agent raises an exception with the message : `Failed to restore agent's checkpoint: 'main_level/agent/main/online/global_step'`

The traceback points to a bug happening in [this rl coach module](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/coach/blob/master/rl_coach/architectures/tensorflow_components/savers.py):

```py
File "/someverylongpath/rl_coach/architectures/tensorflow_components/savers.py", line 93, in <dictcomp>
    for ph, v in zip(self._variable_placeholders, self._variables)
KeyError: 'main_level/agent/main/online/global_step'
```

I use just like Deepracer a [patch on rl coach](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/d6a25381975332aa79df61144fc0c2421bd5168c/reinforcement_learning/rl_deepracer_robomaker_coach_gazebo/src/rl_coach.patch).
One notable thing in the patch is :

```
-        self._variables = tf.global_variables()
+        self._variables = tf.trainable_variables()
```

But shouldn't it result in `'main_level/agent/main/online/global_step'`   not beeing in self._variables ?
The problem i think is that global_step is in self._variables, and it should not be there.

So, there's a few things I don't understand about this problem, and I'm not used to rl coach so any help would be valuable.

1. Why does it fails only the second time ? (Does the graph manager change the computational graph ?)
2. How to avoid global_step to be in self._variables ?

A few more info:

- I use `rl-coach-slim 1.0.0` and `tensorflow 1.11.0`
- Note that I use just like Deepracer a [patch on rl coach](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/d6a25381975332aa79df61144fc0c2421bd5168c/reinforcement_learning/rl_deepracer_robomaker_coach_gazebo/src/rl_coach.patch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the patch (technically I removed the patch command in my dockerfile that was applying it), and now it works, the model is correctly restored from the checkpoint.